# Mod Rewrite URL issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to build SEO friendly URLs, I have this URL:

```
http://www.misite.com?search=&area=$1&cityid=$1&lang=es&subcatid=66&view=ads&catid=9
```

I need to make them look like this SEO friendly URL:

```
http://www.misite.com/sale-houses-california
```

So far, I've added this code to htaccess this:

```
RewriteRule ^sale-houses-([-]?[a-z]+)? ?search=&area=$1&cityid=$1&lang=es&subcatid=66&view=ads&catid=9 [QSA]
```

I have cities, categories and subcategories combining all so I need an easy solution for all of the combinations

I don't know the correct expression: `([-]?[0-9]+)?` / `([-]?[a-z]+)` or similar.

The URL structure is `^text-text-text` in lower case

Is it possible to make something more general like this (see below) or do I have to write a line per each category?

```
RewriteRule ^([-]?[a-z]+)-([-]?[a-z]+)-([-]?[a-z]+)? ?search=&área=$1&cityid=$1&lang=es&subcatid=$1&view=ads&catid=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: can you fix the first URL? you have there `$1` can you change it to what you have on your site so we can better understand what you will have do to? `area=$1` the $1 is a number? a text? same for cityid, if they are numbers you cannot do what you want unless you change that to names.

Comment: i put $1 because i copied from the existing code in the htaccess. i really don't know what it means :) thought i was a variable. lol

Comment: a real url can be eg: http://www.misite.com?search=&area=san+francisco&cityid=99&lang=es&subcatid=66&view=ads&catid=9   area is text with + in between two words. cityid are numbers.

Comment: So your friendly URL would have to be something like `http://www.misite.com/sale-houses-99-san-francisco` otherwise you would have no cityid back is that right?

Comment: i think it can be http://www.misite.com/areaword1+areaword2-99-cityname-11-catname-25-subcatname you have to pass area (text with + in between words), city id (number), catid (numer) and subcatid (number). however, i'd rather have http://www.misite.com/my-own-seo-text-here-areaword1-areaword2 if it's possible

Comment: Sorry your explanation is making no sense compared to the URLs you're demonstrating.

Comment: rewrite this url http://www.misite.com?search=&area=san+francisco&cityid=55&lang=es&subcatid=66&view=ads&catid=9 to Rewrite^houses-san-francisco (being san-francisco the area. only text. "+" between words. catid and subcatid have numbers in database and there are many combinations (area x cat x subcat) and manually it outputs a very large htaccess with low performance. therefore it has to be a rule per categoy or something like that